# group of order 135 solvable?

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

I need to prove that a group G of order 135 is solvable.

$|G| = 135 = 5\cdot 3^3$

i found that the Sylow-subgroups are unique, so they are both normal.
Let H be the Sylow-5-subgroup and F be the Sylow-3-subgroup.

Because they are normal, we can say that:

$G\cong H\times F$

Here is where i get stuck...
I know that H is abelian and hence solvable. But that is it.

Is there a way to prove that F is abelian or solvable? or is this a dead end and do i need to prove this in a whole other way?

Comment: i think not, we haven't seen it in class so i'm no familiar with that theorem...

Comment: @Robbe: The person above you was really making a joke. The joke is that, that theorem requires 255 pages to prove and is complete overkill. (The theorem is that, if a group is odd order, then it is solvable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group with $H\lhd G$.  Then $G$ is solvable if and only if $H$ and $G/H$ are solvable.  Also all $p$-groups are solveable.  So, then $F$ is solvable, and since $(G:F)=5$, $G/F$ is solvable.

Comment: if all p-groups are solvable,then all Sylow-subgroups of any group are solvable, am i right?

Comment: Yes.  That's correct.

Comment: Even better: all *finite* $\;p$-groups are nilpotent (and thus also solvable)

Comment: @Timbuc  You need to be careful here, because if you allow infinite $p$-groups, then it is not true that all $p$-groups are solvable. So the word "finite" needs adding to this answer!

Comment: @DerekHolt,@Timbuc  You two seem to be using a different definition of $p$-group than what I'm familiar with.  According to the definition I know, $p$-groups are finite.  What is your definition?

Comment: A $p$-group is a group in which every element has order a power of $p$. The most extreme examples of infinite $p$-groups are the *Tarski Monsters*, which are infinite simple groups in which all proper subgroups have order $1$ or $p$.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for enlightening me. :)

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't understand: can't you see I wrote *in cursive* the word *finite* ? Of course infinite $\;p$-groups are out of the question: some are even simple!

Comment: @Timbuc: Well, if somebody writes "all $p$-groups are solvable", and you reply "even better: all *finite* $p$-groups are nilpotent", then this strongly suggests that the you agree with the original statement "all $p$-groups are solvable".

Comment: @DerekHolt I can't see how after I clearly remarked *finite* you still can see any suggestion otherwise, honest...not to mention the question was intended to a group of order $\;135\;$ ...finite.

Answer (score 1):

Note that finite $p$-groups are always solvable, since the center is always nontrivial.

Comment: Again, you mean *finite* $p$-groups are always solvable. (Too many people assume that all groups are finite!)

Comment: Whoops, that's right.